# Can't get class list to deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I've got a class containing this bit of code

```
    public static ExpenseItemRoster ReadFromFile(string filename)
    {
        List<ExpenseItemRoster> deserializedExp = null;
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("D:\\myExpensesUpdated.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            deserializedExp = (List<ExpenseItemRoster>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to deserialize Expenses: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

When I try to bring it forth in my main program, I get this:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Payroll.ExpenseItemRoster]'.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm almost certain it's because I'm not returning the deserialized list properly, but I'm not entirely sure if I need to convert the deserialized list into a string, or how to do that.

EDIT: Here's how it's being called...

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Payroll
{
    class PayrollProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create new expenses list
            ExpenseItemRoster expenses = new ExpenseItemRoster();
            //Add original expense items to the expenses list 
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Airline ticket", new DateTime(2010, 3, 7), 365.98m, "myDiscover", "Chicago sales meeting", "Business class"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Dinner", new DateTime(2010, 1, 5), 489m, "cash", "Local sales call", "Client Sam Adams"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Conference fee", new DateTime(2009, 2, 1), 600m, "myDiscover", "Chicago conference", "Prepaid conference fee"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("airline ticket", new DateTime(2009, 12, 20), 1350m, "myVisa", "Emergency customer call", "First class fare"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Lunch", new DateTime(2010, 5, 1), 77m, "myVisa", "Chicago sales meeting", ""));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Dry cleaning", new DateTime(2010, 5, 2), 88m, "cash", "Chicago sales meeting", ""));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Airline Ticket", new DateTime(2010, 11, 12), 8765m, "myVisa", "Australian sales meeting", "first class travel"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Taxi", new DateTime(2011, 3, 13), 101m, "cash", "New York sales manager meeting", "Trip to airport"));
            expenses.Add(new ExpenseItem("Entertainment", new DateTime(2011, 3, 12), 202m, "cash", "New York sales manager meeting", "Airport closed"));
            ExpenseItem e2 = new ExpenseItem("Conference fee", new DateTime(2009, 2, 1), 600m, "myDiscover", "Chicago conference", "Prepaid conference fee");
            try
            {
                expenses.Add(e2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ex.Message, e2.ToString());
            }
            ExpenseItem e1 = new ExpenseItem("Lunch", new DateTime(2010, 5, 1), 77m, "myVisa", "Chicago sales meeting", "");
            expenses.Delete(e1);
            ExpenseItem find = expenses.Find(e1);
            if (find == null)
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found: {0}", e1.ToString());
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Found: {0}", find.ToString());
            try
            {
                expenses.WriteToFile("D:\\myExpensesUpdated.bin");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                ExpenseItemRoster expensesUpdated = ExpenseItemRoster.ReadFromFile("D:\\myExpensesUpdated.bin");
                foreach (var e in expensesUpdated) Console.WriteLine("Updated: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that returning null does nothing useful, however I get the error "can't convert type 'string' to 'Payroll.ExpenseItemRoster'"

I need to somehow convert the deserialized roster into something useable.

Comment: Have you changed the type definition after serializing? Since BinaryFormatter includes type metadata, this *should* usually just work unless you have changed the type - in which case it will die horribly.

Comment: You are hiding the exceptions. By returning null that method is doing nothing useful. Where exactly is this error occurring? How is the object being serialized?

Comment: Can you post the code for ExpenseItemRoster?

Comment: I added some more detail, keep in mind that it's being called form the main program within the namespace but separate .cs file.

Comment: Just curious: have you actually looked in the file to make sure its contents are what you think they should be?

Answer (score 3):

You're writing the `filename` string to the file. I don't understand why would you expect that deserializing that to a `List<ExpenseItemRoster>` would work.

What you probably want to do is:

1. Get rid of the hardcoded filename and use `filename` instead of it.
2. Add a parameter of type `List<ExpenseItemRoster>` to `WriteToFile()` and serialize that.
3. Change the return type of `ReadFromFile()` to `List<ExpenseItemRoster>` and actually `return` the deserialized list.

Answer (score 0):

You're serializing a filename (string) and then you expect it to return to you some list? You need to serialize a list if you want to get a list later.